# Converting a foldl into fold1

Tags: haskell, fold

I am using the following fold to get the final monotonically decreasing sequence of a list.

```
foldl (\acc x -> if x<=(last acc) then acc ++ [x] else [x]) [(-1)] a
```

So `[9,5,3,6,2,1]`  would return `[6,2,1]`
However, with `foldl` I needed to supply a start for the fold namely `[(-1)]`.  I was trying to turn into to a `foldl1` to be able to handle any range of integers as well as any `Ord` a like so:

```
foldl1 (\acc x -> if x<=(last acc) then acc ++ [x] else [x]) a
```

But I get there error:

```
cannot construct infinite type: a ~ [a]
in the second argument of (<=) namely last acc
```

I was under the impression that `foldl1` was basically :

```
foldl (function) [head a] a
```

But I guess this isn't so?  How would you go about making this fold generic for any `Ord` type?

Comment: You know that `last` and `++` work in *O(n)* with *n* the size of the list?

Comment: another reason I was trying to figure out how to make it a foldl1.  I think i could convert it to a foldr1 easily from there and the use head and : operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was under the impression that foldl1 was basically :
>
> ```
> foldl (function) [head a] a
> ```

**No**, `foldl1` is basically:

```
foldl function (head a) (tail a)
```

So the **initial element is not a list of `head a`, but `head a`**.

> How would you go about making this `fold` generic for any `Ord` type?

Well a quick fix is:

```
foldl (\acc x -> if x<=(last acc) then acc ++ [x] else [x]) [head a] (tail a)
```

But there are still two problems:

- in case `a` is an **empty list**, this function will error (while you probably want to return the empty list); and
- the code is not terribly efficient since both `last` and `(++)` run in *O(n)*.

The first problem can easily be addressed by using *pattern matching* to prevent that scenario. But for the latter you better would for instance use a `reverse` approach. Like for instance:

```
f :: Ord t => [t] -> [t]
f [] = [] -- case when the empty list is given
f a = reverse $ foldl (\acc@(ac:_) x -> if x <= ac then (x:acc) else [x]) [head a] (tail a)
```

Furthermore personally I am not a huge fan of `if`-`then`-`else` in functional programming, you can for instance define a helper function like:

```
f :: Ord t => [t] -> [t]
f [] = [] -- case when the empty list is given
f a = reverse $ foldl g [head a] (tail a)
    where g acc@(ac:_) x | x <= ac = (x:acc)
                         | otherwise = [x]
```

Now `reverse` runs in *O(n)* but this is done only *once*. Furthermore the `(:)` construction runs in *O(1)* so all the actions in `g` run in *O(1)* (well given the comparison of course works efficient, etc.) making the algorithm itself *O(n)*.

For your sample input it gives:

```
*Main> f [9,5,3,6,2,1]
[6,2,1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm curious is the where + helper function a stylistic change, or will it actually compile into different code than the if-then-else?  Though I will be changing to the where style since it seems more readable.

Comment: @TonyChamberlain: I honestly don't know. I think the code will be a bit different, but guards are a popular mechanism in Haskell so I expect that performance-wise there is no much difference.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `foldl1` is:

```
Foldable t => (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
```

Your function argument,

```
\acc x -> if x<=(last acc) then acc ++ [x] else [x]
```

has type:

```
(Ord a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
```

When Haskell's typechecker tries typechecking your function, it'll try unifying the type `a -> a -> a` (the type of the first argument of `foldl1`) with the type `[a] -> a -> [a]` (the type of your function).

To unify these types would require unifying `a` with `[a]`, which would lead to the infinite type `a ~ [a] ~ [[a]] ~ [[[a]]]...` and so on.

The reason this works while using `foldl` is that the type of `foldl` is:

`Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`

So `[a]` gets unified with `b` and `a` gets unified with the other `a`, leading to no problem at all.

`foldl1` is limited in that it can only take functions which deal with only one type, or, in other terms,  the accumulator needs to be the same type as the input list (for instance, when folding a list of `Int`s, `foldl1` can only return an `Int`, while `foldl` can use arbitrary accumulators. So you can't do this using `foldl1`).

With regards to making this generic for all `Ord` values, one possible solution is to make a new typeclass for values which state their own "least-bound" value, which would then be used by your function. You can't make this function as it is generic on all `Ord` values because not all `Ord` values have sequence least bounds you can use.

```
class LowerBounded a where
    lowerBound :: a

instance LowerBounded Int where
    lowerBound = -1

finalDecreasingSequence :: (Ord a, LowerBounded a) => [a] -> [a]
finalDecreasingSequence = foldl buildSequence lowerBound
  where buildSequence acc x
    | x <= (last acc) = acc ++ [x]
    | otherwise       = [x]
```

You might also want to read a bit about [how Haskell does its type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system), as it helps a lot in figuring out errors like the one you got.

Comment: Thanks for the insights into the errors.  I've been using :t to look at function types, but just didn't catch the fact that a could be [t] and b could just a b Int in a regular fold.